# iOS 5/6 Twitter sharing without dialog

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter, ios6

i'd like to share to Twitter without the native dialog, is there a way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create your own dialog, and use the [TWRequest API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010942) behind the scenes to invoke Twitter's API.

Reference [Twitter's API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) for the appropriate values to set.

This way you can still take advantage of iOS built in twitter credential handling instead of rolling your own.